# Azure Blob Storage SAS ExpireOn not working

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

**Resolved**, it was the browser cache

I'm trying to get a image from the Azure Blob Storage, and from some reason the ExpireOn its not working, i can access the image fine, but after the expire time passes it's not invalidating the link.

```
import { BlobSASPermissions, generateBlobSASQueryParameters, StorageSharedKeyCredential} from "@azure/storage-blob";

export async function BlobService2(){

  const accountName = process.env.ACCOUNT_NAME;
  const containerName = process.env.CONTAINER_NAME;
  const blobName = process.env.BLOB_NAME;
  const accountKey = process.env.ACCOUNT_KEY;

  const SharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName , accountKey)
  
  const blobSAS = generateBlobSASQueryParameters({
    containerName, // Required
    blobName, // Required
    permissions: BlobSASPermissions.parse("r"), 
    startsOn: new Date(), // Required
    expiresOn: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 5*60000)
    },SharedKeyCredential).toString();
    

  const URL = `https://${accountName}.blob.core.windows.net/${containerName}/${blobName}?${blobSAS}`

  console.log(URL);
  
}
```

Comment: Please check if the browser is not caching the data. I have seen that happening a lot.

Comment: What happens if you access this URL without blobSAS? **curl -v https://${accountName}.blob.core.windows.net/${containerName}/${blobName}** Of course replace with actual values.

Comment: @JohnHanley - Most likely OP will get 404 error (assuming the blob container's ACL is private).

Comment: @GauravMantri - Sometimes users forget to manage access control. Part of collecting data to determine the real problem and to get the OP thinking.

Comment: JohnHanley I get this error : The specified resource does not exist.

@GauravMantri YES! Thank you so much, i've tried using a different browser and i get the invalid link, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

@Henrique E, Thank you for confirming that your issue is resolved by clearing the browser cache.

Thank you @GauravMantri and @JohnHanley for providing your suggestions.